# Reorder Regex Match Groups

Tags: regex, perl, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I am writing a Sublime Text 2 build configuration for grails, which includes a regular expression (perl style) to parse error messages in to file, line, column, and message parts.  The errors come from the grails CLI in the following format:

```
{Project_Directory}/SourceFile.groovy: 19: errror_message @ line 19, column 5.
```

My current regex matches all four parts, but Sublime seems to require that the matches occur in order, that is match group 1 = file name, 2 = line number, 3 = column number, 4 = errror message.  Grails is reporting items 3 and 4 in reverse order, so I need to write a regex that will put the column number in match group 3 and the error message in group 4.  My current regex (which matches, but doesn't reverse groups 3 and 4) is as follows:

```
^(.+?): (\d+): (.+?) \@ line \d+, column (\d+)\.$
```

Any ideas?  Is this even possible?  Does anybody know if sublime will accept named groups instead of numbered groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(.+?): (\d+): (?=.+? \@ line \d+, column (\d+)\.$)(.+?) \@
```

Better (less backtracking on failure):

```
^([^:]+): (\d+): (?=[^@]+ \@ line \d+, column (\d+)\.$)([^@]+) \@
```

Comment: Sorry, [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/hf9NKiY6QS) shows that this has no matches in the specified error string.

Comment: From all the spaces, I thought you were using /x. Fixed and tested.

Comment: perfect!  genius way to use the zero width assertions, too.  I didn't know you could have a named group inside one.  very cool.  Thanks!