# file_regex for Cargo builds in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, rust-cargo

### Question

What would be the right `file_regex` to capture Cargo / Rustc's error messages in a Sublime Text 3 build system? I'm asking specifically about relatively recent cargo/rustc versions (it seems that the older versions used a somewhat more easily parsable single-line error output format).

### Example

Example output of `cargo build` on a broken hello-world project (default code autogenerated by `cargo new --bin broken`, with one double quote removed to create an error message):

```
error: unterminated double quote string
 --> src/main.rs:2:14
  |
2 |       println!("Hello, world!);
  |  ______________^
3 | | }
  | |__^

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `broken`.
```

The relative file path is `src/main.rs`, line-column is `2:14`, the error message that I personally would prefer to see directly between the lines is

```
unterminated double quote string
```

---

### 1st Solution Attempt

This kind-of works, but it doesn't capture the error messages properly, because they are on a separate line that *preceeds* the line with the file path and line numbers:

```
    {
        "name": "cargo build",
        "shell_cmd": "cargo build",
        "working_dir": 
          "/home/you/path/to/cargo/project/with/the/toml",
        "file_regex": 
          "^ *--> *([a-zA-Z0-9_/.]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)()$"
    },
```

### 2nd Solution Attempt

This [funny regex here](https://regex101.com/r/JjfVgl/1) that uses [this awesome lookahead-with-matching-groups-trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11230878/2707792):

```
error(?:\[E\d+\])?: (?=.+\n +--> +([a-zA-Z0-9_\/.-]+):([\d]+):([\d]+))(.+)
```

would have solved the problem, but [Sublime doesn't seem to work with multiline regexes](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1430).

---

Comment: Can you include a sample of an error output? Along with `file_regex` there is also `line_regex` that can be paired with it for situations where the error output is on two lines. However it works by matching `line_regex` and then going backwards to get the file, so if the outputs are in the wrong order it may not work.

Comment: @OdatNurd I've updated the question with an example error message. Thanks for the hint with `line_regex`, will look up what that is, didn't know about it.

Comment: `line_regex` doesn't seem to help here: it's only for the cases where file name and line/column are on different lines, but it does not help me to permute the matched groups into the right order.

Comment: Indeed so, unfortunately. Only the `file_regex` can match the name of the file, while the `line_regex` can match everything BUT the file; in use the two merge together but since it matches line and then goes backwards to get the file, the output of this is in the wrong order.

Comment: In such a case as far as I'm aware the only way to get it to be able to determine the error message in this case is to massage the output of the tool to conform to what Sublime expects. If you're only interested in inline build errors and not clickable build results, it's possible with some work to modify the internal `exec` command to handle something like this, but that's more involved.

Comment: @OdatNurd I'm of course also open for suggestions about how to modify cargo's output. It has the option `cargo build --message-format=...`, but it takes as arguments only `json` and `human`. The `human`-format is what you see here, the `json`-format is something that I definitely don't want to parse by regex ;) Rewriting cargo's error messages with AWK would be possible, but it feels way too "hacked".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AWK script combines the error message with the line numbers, and brings it into the order that Sublime wants:

```
awk 'BEGIN { errmsg="" } /error(\[E[0-9]+\])?:.*/ {errmsg=$0; next} /\ *-->\ *.*/ { printf "%s::::%s\n", $0, errmsg; next} {print $0}'
```

The output is trivially matched by the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZQM2n8/2):

```
error(?:\[E\d+\])?: (?=.+\n +--> +([a-zA-Z0-9_\/.-]+):([\d]+):([\d]+))(.+)
```

You can use `|` and AWK scripts inside the `shell_cmd`, so this build config captures all the error messages and displays them at the correct line numbers:

```
{
    "name": "cargo build",
    "working_dir": "/wherever/your/project",
    "shell_cmd": "cargo build 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { errmsg=\"\" } /error(\\[E[0-9]+\\])?:.*/ {errmsg=\\$0; next} /\\ *-->\\ *.*/ { printf \"%s::::%s\\n\", \\$0, errmsg; next} {print \\$0}'",
    "file_regex": " +--> +([a-zA-Z_\\/.-]+):(\\d+):(\\d+)::::(.*)"
}
```

This also treats `warning`s in the same way:

```
"shell_cmd": "cargo build 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { errmsg=\"\" } /(error|warning)(\\[E[0-9]+\\])?:.*/ {errmsg=\\$0; next} /\\ *-->\\ *.*/ { printf \"%s::::%s\\n\", \\$0, errmsg; next} {print \\$0}'",
```

Answer (score 3):

The TL;DR version of the answer is that unfortunately I think the only way to get Sublime to recognize the error output in your question is to either make the tool generate output in a different format (either directly or by way of some filter app that sits in the middle) or by creating your own custom build target for your build that can recognize this error output (but it would only work for inline errors, see below).

#### Background

Build systems in Sublime Text have two regular expressions that can be applied to try and match error output/build results, `file_regex` and `line_regex`. Both are applied to the results of the build in the output panel in order to obtain the list of build results.

`file_regex` is the "general purpose" regex for matching build results, and should contain anywhere from 2 to 4 capture groups that capture the appropriate data. The capture groups (used in order) are `filename`, `line`, `column`, `message`.

`line_regex` is used in cases where the information about location of the error is on a different line than the error message/location. Here the captures are in the order `line`, `column`, `message` and you can use anywhere from 1 to 3 of them.

In both cases the captures are used in the order given above, which can necessitate having empty capture groups to make sure things line up as expected.

In normal use you just use `file_regex` and nothing else, and that captures the results for you. If you also use `line_regex`, then internally Sublime matches on `line_regex` instead, and then if it finds a match, it looks backwards through the result output for the first line that matches `file_regex`, and combines the results from the captures together.

Inherently this means that there are some restrictions placed on the sort of results that Sublime can capture; the file name has to appear prior to the other information about the error in order for it to be captured.

#### Massaging the output

In your example above, the error is displayed first and the location for the error is displayed second, so inherently there's no way to correctly associate the two regular expression matches together.

The most common way around this is to modify the output of the tool in order to rework it into a format that Sublime can detect with the above regular expressions.

For example you might change your build so that it executes your command and pipes the result to another shell script or program that can alter the information on the fly as it goes through. Another example would be to alter your build so that it invokes a script/batch file that executes the tool and does the output alteration internally, so that the final output matches what Sublime expects.

#### Custom build targets

Although there's no way to use the regex system to match your build output fully, if you're primarily interested in inline build errors being displayed, there is some recourse if you want to get your hands dirty with a little Sublime plugin development. In this case you need to know a bit of Python. There is documentation on [custom build targets](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html#advanced_example) as well as the [Sublime API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) available.

Internally, when you run a build, Sublime gathers the information from the `sublime-build` file, expands any variables in it, and then invokes the `exec` internal command to actually perform the build providing the keys in the `sublime-build` as arguments (some, such as `selector`, are not provided because Sublime handles that for you), and it's the `exec` command that sets the `file_regex` and `line_regex` settings into the output buffer.

From here, the applied settings are used by the Sublime core directly to perform navigation on build results, such as by clicking on the results to open the file, or using the navigation commands to go to the next and previous errors.

However, it's the `exec` command that is responsible for using those same results to show you the inline build errors, so it's possible to still get inline error messages working, although result navigation can only take you to the location in the file.

One of the keys that you can provide in a `sublime-build` file is `target`, which specifies the command that should execute the build; this defaults to `exec` if not given.

By creating your own custom command that mimics what `exec` does and using it in the `target` directive of your `sublime-build`, you can hook into the build process to capture the appropriate data.

The `exec` command is stored in `Default/exec.py`, which you can view by using the `View Package File` command from the command palette.

As a minimal example, the following plugin defines a new command named `cargo_exec` which exactly mimics what the `exec` command does. The call to `self.output_view.find_all_results_with_text()` is the API call that makes the Sublime core return all of the error information from the build output view, which is used to set up the phantoms used for inline build errors.

By modifying that code to examine the contents of the buffer and use your custom knowledge of what errors look like, the remainder of the code in the core `exec` command will display the inline errors for you.

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

from Default.exec import ExecCommand

# Subclass the exec command to hook into the output processing.
class CargoExecCommand(ExecCommand):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        # If we are being told to kill a running build, kill it right away
        # and leave.
        if kwargs.get("kill", False):
            return super().run(kill=True)

        # Use our super class to execute the build from this point.
        super().run(**kwargs)

    # override the super class method so we can handle output as it
    # arrives in the output panel.
    def service_text_queue(self):
        is_empty = False
        with self.text_queue_lock:
            if len(self.text_queue) == 0:
                # this can happen if a new build was started, which will clear
                # the text_queue
                return

            characters = self.text_queue.popleft()
            is_empty = (len(self.text_queue) == 0)

        self.output_view.run_command(
            'append',
            {'characters': characters, 'force': True, 'scroll_to_end': True})

        if self.show_errors_inline and characters.find('\n') >= 0:
            errs = self.output_view.find_all_results_with_text()
            errs_by_file = {}
            for file, line, column, text in errs:
                if file not in errs_by_file:
                    errs_by_file[file] = []
                errs_by_file[file].append((line, column, text))
            self.errs_by_file = errs_by_file

            self.update_phantoms()

        if not is_empty:
            sublime.set_timeout(self.service_text_queue, 1)


# Use the latest build results to add inline errors to newly opened files.
class CargoExecEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        w = view.window()
        if w is not None:
            w.run_command('cargo_exec', {'update_phantoms_only': True})
```

To use this as a custom build target, you need to add a couple of extra keys to your `sublime-build` file:

```json
// Specify a custom build target to execute this build, and specify what
// argument to the command will cause it to cancel a build that is currently
// running.
"target": "cargo_exec",
"cancel": {"kill": true},
```

Comment: That's impressive, but I somehow expected that passing four strings from one program to another shouldn't take much more than a single line of configuration. It even *almost* works without any massaging of the output: if `rustc` used `print` instead of `println`, it would work; likewise, had Sublime allowed to use multiline regex, then it would work too. I decided to use an AWK script to rewrite the error messages into the format that Sublime wants. It's ugly, but it fits into the said one (long) line, and it has no chance of sprawling into a "pet project" that will haunt me forever.

Comment: Indeed, this is one of the pitfalls of the current way this works and many are unhappy with it to some degree or another (including myself). Other failings include that even with the current system, items must appear in a certain order in `file_regex` or the capture groups don't capture what you expect.

Comment: The order is not the problem: you can work around it using lookaheads, Sublime's regex flavor supports it (see second solution attempt in the question for an example: it reorders 4 1 2 3 into 1 2 3 4). Still, writing an entire plugin simply because of a whim of some compiler-writer who decided to add too many line breaks seems like a disproportionally heavyweight solution. I think it's not even really sublime's responsibility: configuring *parsing* is much harder than configuring *formatted printout*. It would be much easier to fix on the side that emits the error messages.

Comment: Anyway, I thank you for your effort and the detailed explanation. I will keep this answer in mind as a possible entry point into sublime plugin development.